# Host GAE app on a domain without purchasing a Google Apps account for that domain?

Tags: google-app-engine, dns, google-apps

I have purchased my own domain name, and I have created an App Engine app.  I'd like to configure GAE so that the app can be served off the domain name that I own.

It appears as though I must create a Google Apps account for that domain in order to host the GAE app on that domain. This costs $50 per year, which I'd rather not pay.

Is there any free way to host a GAE app on my domain name?

Comment: Google it in the appengine issues page. This is well documented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Using a Custom Domain
>
> When you create an application with Google App Engine, the app is
>   automatically served on the appspot.com domain at
>   your-app-ID.appspot.com. However, it's often desirable to serve your
>   app at a custom domain that you own (example.com), at specific
>   subdomains of that domain (app.example.com), or at any or all
>   (*.example.com) subdomains of that domain.
>
> It's easy to do this with App Engine. First, of course, you must
>   acquire a domain through a domain registrar. Once you have a domain,
>   customizing your app to use your domain or subdomain involves three
>   steps:
>
> ```
> Prove to Google that you control the domain.
> Configure Google servers to recognize the domain.
> Update the DNS records at your domain registrar to point to Google servers.
> ```
>
> The entire process can typically be completed in a few minutes at your
>   computer.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/domain

Comment: I had always been using the old Google App Engine "Application Settings" page <https://appengine.google.com/settings> whereas the Google Developers Console <https://console.developers.google.com/> has a Compute > App Engine > Settings > Custom Domain page that appears to enable using a custom domain without purchasing a $50 per user per year Google Apps account. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

It's not possible, you need a Google Apps account. But I think it's possible to create a free account with just one user (admin).